# ASP.NET Controls under the hood

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-controls

I want to learn (basically) about how ASP.NET controls work. I know the end result has to be some kinda rendered HTML. How do the controls encapsulate stuff? How does it tie in to the whole ASP.NET flow? My team has written a widgets library that wraps the native controls and then adds custom styling etc etc. and I need to be contributing to this library. Many thank you's

Answer (score 2):

The two places I would start would be [Truly Understanding Dynamic Controls](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/25/TRULY-Understanding-Dynamic-Controls-_2800_Part-1_2900_.aspx) and [Truly Understanding Viewstate](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate.aspx).

Comment: Hi. Took a look at these links and they look good. Are they still relevant today?

Answer (score 1):

Learning the [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) is important to answering your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Nikhil Kothari has written the Bible for this, entitled "Developing Microsoft ASP.NET Server Controls and Components". You can pick up a copy here for less than a dollar :-)

http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/0735615829/ref=dp_olp_used?ie=UTF8&condition=used